Identify a movie about a toy factory
Movie about a toy factory.
At the end they make a music chip for a toy bear and save the factory from being closed down.

Approximate years: 2006-2009 
Origin of country of release: USA 
Live action & colour
It also has no singing in it
English language maybe on Disney or Nickelodeon or Cartoon-Network.

Plot: The kids take over the toy factory from their mom and dad and use a PC to talk to them.

Please see Identify-This-X Questions guide on how to write good identify this movie question. For example add better descriptive title, origin-country, colour, language,plot, details etc. of the movie.

I think this may be The Braniacs.com (2000)

When a boy decides his father is spending too much time at work, he starts his own company and ends up buying a controlling interest in his father's company.
IMDB

It seems to have many elements (date apart) that match your question...

To achieve his goal of more time with his widowed, workaholic father David, Matt Tyler and his best friend Danny decide to try to buy his business, Tyler Toys.
Matt buys a majority share in Tyler Toys (see Wikipedia link for how)
As the new boss "Mr. Chips" (animated by a computer) institutes lax work regulations and gives his father a vacation.
Tyler Toys survives long enough for the microchip to be completed, which sees its first use metamorphosizing the Hairball (not a bear though) into the intelligent, interactive Smartball;

A couple of video which might help






